# MongoDB: Nested aggregation

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, nosql

I have multiple collections:

**users - collection schema**

History is a sub-document of user collection/document

```
name: "jacob"
_id: 5fc53209e70f776378cce0c5,
history: [
  {
     _id: 5fc634bee65f96338a63b9e4,
     article: 5fc5f3e6140646c2024f7963,
     created_at: 2010-12-01T12:19:10.121+00:00
  },
  {
    _id: 5fc634d8e65f96338a63b9e5,
    article: 5fc5faaa8b1fffc1f4dec900,
    created_at: 2010-12-01T12:19:36.102+00:00
  }
]
```

**articles - collection schema**

```
{
   _id: 5fc5faaa8b1fffc1f4dec900,
   title: "hello there",
   author: 5fc531cae70f776378cce0c4 // Author is related to user collection
},
{
   _id: 5fc5f3e6140646c2024f7963,
   title: "hello wonderland",
   author: 5fc531cae70f776378cce0c4 // Author is related to user collection
}
```

Is it possible to `$lookup` the article in history, then `$lookup` the author of the article? And also sort by date of history?

**Desired Output**

```
...
name: "jacob",
_id: 5fc53209e70f776378cce0c5,
history: [
  {
     _id: 5fc634bee65f96338a63b9e4,
     article: {
        _id: 5fc5faaa8b1fffc1f4dec900,
        title: "hello there",
        author: {
           _id: 5fc531cae70f776378cce0c4,
           name: "melissa"
        }
     },
     created_at: 2010-12-01T12:19:10.121+00:00
  },
  {
    _id: 5fc634d8e65f96338a63b9e5,
    article: {
       _id: 5fc5faaa8b1fffc1f4dec900,
       title: "hello wonderland",
       author: {
          _id: 5fc531cae70f776378ccedsu8,
         name: "omelia",
       }
    },
    created_at: 2010-11-12T2:19:36.102+00:00
  }
]
```

> NOTE: Sorted by date in descending order

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try,

- `$unwind` deconstruct `history` array
- `$lookup` join articles collection, let to pass article id,

  - `$match` to match article id
  - `$lookup` to join with users collection
  - `$unwind` deconstruct users because its array
  - `$project` to show required fields
- `$unwind` deconstruct article array
- `$sort` by `created_at` date
- `$group` by id and reconstruct `history` array

```
db.users.aggregate([
  { $unwind: "$history" },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "articles",
      let: { articleId: "$history.article" },
      pipeline: [
        { $match: { $expr: { $eq: ["$_id", "$$articleId"] } } },
        {
          $lookup: {
            from: "users",
            localField: "author",
            foreignField: "_id",
            as: "author"
          }
        },
        { $unwind: "$author" },
        {
          $project: {
            _id: 1,
            author: { _id: 1, name: 1 },
            title: 1
          }
        }
      ],
      as: "history.article"
    }
  },
  { $unwind: "$history.article" },
  { $sort: { "history.created_at": -1 } },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$_id",
      history: { $push: "$history" },
      name: { $first: "$name" }
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/JaKWdKWB9e4)